# SoundCloud Api - unable to get all the favorites of a certain user

Tags: php, soundcloud

I'm trying to get all the favorites of a certain user.
I used `/users/{id}/favorites`, but the returned list always has the last 50 favorited tracks, and I couldn't find a "next_href" or anything to get the rest.

Is there any way to get the whole list? Or is it just me who made something wrong and it's working perfect for everybody?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to make batch page requests with offset=0,50,100,etc parameter in the url. and join the results when all pages (tracks) are loaded.

Comment: This. And to expand on it; the offset is often a multiple of the `limit` parameter (which defaults to 50 if you don't pass it). You can increase the limit to (I think) 200, decreasing the amount of requests you have to do to fetch all favorites.